# How to change the id of an Entity type in Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, propel

In one of my form type, I am generating a select widget for a given entity (**Symfony 2.4 + Propel 1.7**) , I'd like to change the value (for the select widget options) for the slug column not the primary key which is a basic auto-increment. I'd like to avoid using a choice type and populate the data by hand (+having to create a corresponding data transformer to get the entity). What is the best way to achieve that?

I'd like:

```
<!-- type1 is the slug column of the entity -->
<option value="type1">Type 1</option>
```

Instead of:

```
<option value="1">Type 1</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look a the enitytype, you'll notice that it extends the doctrinetype.  in the doctrinetype you'll see a setDefaultOptions method where it sets the choices.  basically you'd need to extend the entitytype and override the setDefaultOptions method that is originally provided by the doctrineType.

honestly though, it's a bit easier to just use a choice field + datatransformer in my opinion.

Comment: It's not Doctrine but Propel, but I suppose it could be the same kind of solution. I must give a try.